After Bootstrap upgrade in Angular project, custom table CSS is no longer being applied
I have an Angular project and import my styles.scss file in angular.json:
"styles": [
     "src/scss/styles.scss"
 ],

In the styles.scss file, I import bootstrap:
$table-striped-order: even;
$table-active-bg: rgba(102, 102, 102);

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "./variables";
@import "./mixins";

Also in my styles.scss file, I have the table styles that formerly worked great:
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 25px 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: $main-font;
  min-width: 400px;

  thead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    tr {
      background-color: $lt-gray;
      color: $black;
      text-align: left;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  }

  tbody {
    tr {
      color: $mallard;

      &:nth-of-type(even) {
        background-color: $white-smoke;
      }

      &:last-of-type {
        border-bottom: 2px solid $mallard;
      }

      &:hover {
        background-color: $mercury !important;
        color: $dim-gray !important;
      }

      td {
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

This was working with "bootstrap": "~5.2.3" and "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.1.2" set in package.json. Upgrading to "bootstrap": "^5.3.2" and "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0" seems to have broken that.
I did not see anything that jumped out at me when I review the update notes for bootstrap and ng-bootstrap.
I have experimented with several SASS variables, and that has helped some, but the issue is editing those can affect areas that I do not wish to change. For instance, I changed one for the background attempting to modify the thead, but it also modified the tbody.
I have tried with no effect:

Changing from element selector to setting it as a class and applying it.
Using [ngClass] to try and set it both statically and dynamically.
Using very specific selectors and even ng-deep
Moving the bootstrap import to the end of the file

I have other custom CSS such as for button styles and fonts in the styles.scss file that are still working correctly.
